# Karma Jasmine and TypeScript

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm having an issue when attempting to run Unit Tests with `karma-jasmine` + `typescript` + `karma-typescript-preprocessor`.

I keep getting the following error in the stack trace:

```
23 04 2016 14:53:46.194:ERROR [preprocessor.typescript]: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
 at /home/booyanach/WebstormProjects/cookie-wrapper/src/cookie.wrapper.spec.ts
TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
    at TypeScriptSimple.toJavaScript (/home/booyanach/WebstormProjects/cookie-wrapper/node_modules/typescript-simple/index.js:162:28)
    at TypeScriptSimple.compile (/home/booyanach/WebstormProjects/cookie-wrapper/node_modules/typescript-simple/index.js:71:25)
    at /home/booyanach/WebstormProjects/cookie-wrapper/node_modules/karma-typescript-preprocessor/index.js:22:26
    at nextPreprocessor (/home/booyanach/WebstormProjects/cookie-wrapper/node_modules/karma/lib/preprocessor.js:35:26)
    at /home/booyanach/WebstormProjects/cookie-wrapper/node_modules/karma/lib/preprocessor.js:114:9
    at module.exports (/home/booyanach/WebstormProjects/cookie-wrapper/node_modules/isbinaryfile/index.js:28:12)
    at /home/booyanach/WebstormProjects/cookie-wrapper/node_modules/karma/lib/preprocessor.js:79:7
    at /home/booyanach/WebstormProjects/cookie-wrapper/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:404:3)
```

And here's my karma.conf.file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: './',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      { pattern: './**/*.ts', included: false }
    ],
    exclude: [
        'dist/',
        'node_modules/',
        'typings/',
        'coverage/'
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/*.ts': ['typescript']
    },
    typescriptPreprocessor: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: false,
        target: 'ES5',
        module: 'commonjs'
      },
      transformPath: function(path) {
        return path.replace(/\.ts$/, '.js');
      },
      typings: [
        'typings/browser.d.ts'
      ]
    },
    reporters: [],
    port: 9999,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: true,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
};
```

Note: cookie.wrapper.spec.ts is not empty